# How to place path variable in Get request in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, get, path-variables

```js
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('/api/v3/products', {
            params: {
                pageNumber: 1,
                pageSize: 500,
            }
        })
```

I know how to place params in Get request, but don't know how to place a path variable, could somebody help?

```js
<Route path='/product/:id' component={Product}/>
```

tried to write "/product/:path", but I think, it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Can you explain more please? what I understood, you want to make children roots from that route `/product/child-route`, is that correct?

Comment: I've got some products in /api/v3/products, I want to get detail info about one of them, so need to make get request to /api/v3/product/{id}, where {id} is a path variable. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example Route:
`<Route path='/product/:productId' component={Product}/>`

Inside your component `Product`

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { productId } = this.props.match.params
    // Extracted productId from the Route params.
    axios.get(`/api/v3/product/${productId}`, { // used productId in our GET Request
        params: {
            pageNumber: 1,
            pageSize: 500,
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Make sure you use `productId` in both `Route` component, and `componentDidMount()` the same as it's written. this should work without errors.

Comment: whoops, I was wrong, it worked, I wrote ' instead of `, thanks

Comment: Perfect, Good job :+1:

Answer (score 0):

Look's like I found an solution:

axios.get("/api/v3/product/" + id)
...

where I can get an Id of each product by setState and give it by onClick